# Docker daemon access denied while running from github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-registry, build-server, harbor

i am currently trying to setup the Github - actions and use windows VM as build server (self hosted runner). i have installed docker on windows.
i am able to connect to our harbor regisrty from windows VM
example screenshot from powershell : [Able to successfully run the docker command in windows VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX3lX.png)

but, when i try to execute the same command from github actions, i am getting access denied error

please refer the following screenshot from github-actions :
[Access denied error when running docker command from github actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCCY4.png)

can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the startup params of the Docker Engine service to point to the User group installed with the Github actions runner.  I also had to make this modification using the registry editor as the GUI for the services would not accept a parameter change, more on this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/507561/in-a-windows-service-will-the-start-parameters-be-preserved-if-the-start-is-of

Example: "C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe" --run-service -G GITHUB_ActionsRunner_XXXXXX"